# How to use afconvert to convert from .caf to .mp3 format?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am using the afconvert command line utility to convert an audio file from `.caf` to `.mp3` format. I have used `afconvert`:

```
afconvert -f 'MPG3 ' -d '.mp3' -v input.caf output.mp3
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Input file: input.caf, 19008 frames
Error: ExtAudioFileSetProperty ('cfmt') failed ('fmt?')
```

I have also tried the following:

```
afconvert -f 'MPG3 ' -d LEI32@44100 -v input.caf  output.mp3
```

This also gives me the error:

```
Input file: min.caf, 19008 frames
Error: ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL failed ('fmt?')
```

I couldn't figure out why is this giving error.

Can anybody guide me in solving this problem?

Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 23):

you should check this,

```
afconvert -f mp4f -d aac -b 128000   input.caf output2.mp4
```

This way you will convert your CAF file to the MPEG-4 format.

Read: Apple does not ship any form of MP3 encoder with Mac OS X aside from the one built into iTunes. 
source: http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2005/Jul/msg00182.html

you should use 3rd party encoders if you need to encode mp3 
Mp3 Encoder examples: lame encoder or ffmpeg :) good luck.

Comment: afconvert -f mp4f -d aac -b 128000   input.caf output2.mp3 works for me

Comment: -1 wrong. that just creates an mpeg4 audio file with an mp3 extension.

Comment: For me, using `afconvert` this way creates an mp3 file with additional length and a little bit less in volume. So I use iTunes to [convert a song to mp3](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1550?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the LAME encoder (On Mac, run `brew install lame` to install it).

First, you'll have to convert caf to wav (I had no chance to check if LAME supports caf as input, but it supports wav for sure).
Then run

```
lame --alt-preset cbr 128 sample.wav
```

This will create mp3 file with 128 kbps constant bitrate.
LAME has lot of settings, you can choose mp3 parameters as you wish.

Comment: the command "sudo port install lame" doesnt work.

Comment: Install homebrew http://brew.sh/ then
brew install lame

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
afconvert -f mp4f -d aac -v input.caf output.mp3
```

I know it's not exactly mp3, but I couldn't get around that same error you are getting, so I tried mp4f and it worked.