# How to record audio in .aac, .mp3, .wav format

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I am new in ios developement.I have created a simple voice recording using file extension of .caf format. It will record in .caf file.while tap the play button it working fine.But I want to record in .aac,mp3,wav format and also i need to implement quality like low,medium, high.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can achieve is convert the .caf file to .wav or .mp3 after you have downloaded it successfully.

Here some ways are mentioned

[How to use afconvert to convert from .caf to .mp3 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435349/how-to-use-afconvert-to-convert-from-caf-to-mp3-format)

[Converting mp3 to caf file for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670389/converting-mp3-to-caf-file-for-iphone?rq=1)

[How to convert a wav or caf audio file on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763738/how-to-convert-a-wav-or-caf-audio-file-on-iphone)

Please have a look at them . Hope they help.

Comment: I need to convert recorded .caf audio file into .aac audio file... any idea how to do this?

Comment: is it possible to recorded some other audio file format to convert .aac file in ios?

Comment: please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801015/iphone-how-to-convert-caf-audio-files-into-aac

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem.I wanted to record audio in .mp3 format, but i didn't find any code for doing that.But what you can do is you can rename the extension of your audio file.
You just rename extension .caf to .mp3 and it also works great..

You can check it..

Cheers,

Nirav

Comment: i tried it. it works fine but i think rename extension is not a proper way

Comment: Renaming isn't proper way.

Comment: i knew my friends, but i searched whole internet, but i didn't find a good way to record in .mp3. If you can find a way, please please tell me.

Comment: There is not way to record file in .mp3 extension but you need to convert recorded .caf file into .mp3 file using proper setting of mp3 standards, AVFoundation framework will help you on such functioanlity.

Comment: @iAmbitious I need to convert recorded .caf audio file into .aac audio file... any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can record a wav file by setting AVFormatIDKey to kAudioFormatLinearPCM