# iPhone - How to convert .caf audio files into .aac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, aac, caf

I am working on audio recording. I am able to record my audio in caf (Core audio format).i followed this tutorial [Recording Audio on an iPhone with AVAudioRecorder](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29). Now I don't  want to record sound in .aac format directly, I need to convert recorded .caf audio file into .aac audio file... any idea how to do this?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface recordViewController : UIViewController
    <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    UIButton *playButton;
    UIButton *recordButton;
    UIButton *stopButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
-(IBAction) recordAudio;
-(IBAction) playAudio;
-(IBAction) stop;
@end

#import "recordViewController.h"

@implementation recordViewController
@synthesize playButton, stopButton, recordButton;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
playButton.enabled = NO;
stopButton.enabled = NO;

NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
        AVEncoderBitRateKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
        AVSampleRateKey,
        nil];

NSError *error = nil;

audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
              initWithURL:soundFileURL
              settings:recordSettings
              error:&error];

if (error)
{
       NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

} else {
       [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}
}
-(void) recordAudio
{
 if (!audioRecorder.recording)
 {
         playButton.enabled = NO;
         stopButton.enabled = YES;
         [audioRecorder record];
 }
}
-(void)stop
{
stopButton.enabled = NO;
playButton.enabled = YES;
recordButton.enabled = YES;

if (audioRecorder.recording)
{
        [audioRecorder stop];
} else if (audioPlayer.playing) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
}
}
-(void) playAudio
{
if (!audioRecorder.recording)
{
   stopButton.enabled = YES;
   recordButton.enabled = NO;

    if (audioPlayer)
          [audioPlayer release];
    NSError *error;

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
    initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                                    
    error:&error];

    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    if (error)
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", 
          [error localizedDescription]);
    else
          [audioPlayer play];
}
}

 -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
 {
    recordButton.enabled = YES;
    stopButton.enabled = NO;
 }

 -(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
 {
    NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
 }

 -(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
 {
 }

 -(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder error:(NSError *)error
 {
    NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
 }
@end
```

Comment: does this help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html and another tute http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/

Comment: @Smick i already tried it.first one iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest sample project while convert .caf into .aac file conversion is fine but it does not play... second one TPAACAudioConverter project everything working fine except .aac conversion

Comment: I look forward to seeing this one solved. I tried to do a frequency app to change music to 432Hz.... couldn't solve it. I'll up vote this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

step 1) I have downloaded sample TPAACAudioConverter project from https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter

step 2)**AACConverterViewController.m**

i have set source file and destination file format

```
- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender {
if ( ![TPAACAudioConverter AACConverterAvailable] ) {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Converting audio", @"")
                                 message:NSLocalizedString(@"Couldn't convert audio: Not supported on this device", @"")
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                       otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
}

// Initialise audio session, and register an interruption listener, important for AAC conversion
if ( !checkResult(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListener, self), "initialise audio session") ) {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Converting audio", @"")
                                 message:NSLocalizedString(@"Couldn't initialise audio session!", @"")
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                       otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
}


// Set up an audio session compatible with AAC conversion.  Note that AAC conversion is incompatible with any session that provides mixing with other device audio.
UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
if ( !checkResult(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory), "setup session category") ) {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Converting audio", @"")
                                 message:NSLocalizedString(@"Couldn't setup audio category!", @"")
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                       otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
} 

NSArray *documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
audioConverter = [[[TPAACAudioConverter alloc] initWithDelegate:self 
                                                         source:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"aiff"]
                                                    destination:[[documentsFolders objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.m4a"]] autorelease];
((UIButton*)sender).enabled = NO;
[self.spinner startAnimating];
self.progressView.progress = 0.0;
self.progressView.hidden = NO;

[audioConverter start];
}
```

**play converted audio**

```
- (IBAction)playConverted:(id)sender {
if ( audioPlayer ) {
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer release];
    audioPlayer = nil;
    [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Play converted" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    NSArray *documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentsFolders objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.aac"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [audioPlayer play];

    [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

step 3)**TPAACAudioConverter.m**

simply i have changed audio file type find and replace **kAudioFileM4AType** into **kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType**